# Add to an ObservableCollection<T> using OpenFileDIalog

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, openfiledialog

I have a MainPage and MainPageViewModel and on the viewmodel I have the following property I am binding a listview to:

```
public ObservableCollection<TargetDrawingModel> TargetDrawings { get; set; }
```

On the viewmodel I have the following method(run by a corresponding command my button is bound to):

```
private void AddTargetDrawingClick()
{
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    TargetDrawings.Add(da.AddtoTargetDrawingList());
}
```

Finally, the AddToTargetDrawingList() method in the DataAccess class:

```
public TargetDrawingModel AddtoTargetDrawingList()
{
    TargetDrawingModel output = new TargetDrawingModel();

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Title = "Select The Target Drawings To Add To Add To The Comparison";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Drawing (*.dwg) | *.dwg";
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        foreach (string file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            TargetDrawingModel targetDrawing = new TargetDrawingModel();
            targetDrawing.DrawingPath = file;
            return targetDrawing;
        }
    }
    output.DrawingPath = "nothing added";
    return output;
}
```

The method works to add files, but if my user does not select a drawing (cancels the open file dialog), I *don't want* to return anything, however, if I don't provide a return value, the method will not build because "Not all code paths return a value."  That's why I'm currently returning the string "nothing added" but that obviously won't do.

I suspect because I'm calling the Add method on `ObservableCollection<TargetDrawingModel>`. It requires that I return something but I'm not sure how to do it differently.

How can I modify this method to allow the user to cancel out and select nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify result before adding to collection:

```
var result = da.AddtoTargetDrawingList();
if (result != null && result.DrawingPath != "nothing added")
    TargetDrawings.Add(result);
```

---

`AddtoTargetDrawingList` uses multiselect FileDialog, which mean you have to return multiple items:

```
public IList<TargetDrawingModel> AddtoTargetDrawingList()
{
    var items = new List<TargetDrawingModel>();

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Title = "Select The Target Drawings To Add To Add To The Comparison";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Drawing (*.dwg) | *.dwg";
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        foreach (string file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            TargetDrawingModel targetDrawing = new TargetDrawingModel();
            targetDrawing.DrawingPath = file;
            items.Add(targetDrawing);
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

```
foreach(var result in da.AddtoTargetDrawingList())
{
    TargetDrawings.Add(result);
}
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you. And I'll update my method to use IList as well.

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out. Would have tripped me up again. Still learning the ropes with playing with collections.

Comment: @Kefka, so, to clarify: if user cancels FileDialog, method will return empty list. if user chose 1 or more file, they will be added to list, returned from method and added to collection

Answer (score 2):

In the `AddtoTargetDrawingList` method, you are executing a return-statement inside a loop, but the method will exit at the first return-statement encountered and will always only return one item. If you want to return several files, you could use [yield return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield). This turns the method into an iterator. The return type must then be an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public IEnumerable<TargetDrawingModel> GetTargetDrawingModels()
{
    using (var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() {
        Title = "Select The Target Drawings To Add To Add To The Comparison",
        Filter = "Drawing (*.dwg) | *.dwg",
        Multiselect = true
    }) {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog()) {
            foreach (string file in openFileDialog.FileNames) {
                yield return new TargetDrawingModel { DrawingPath = file };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can create the collection with

```
TargetDrawings = new ObservableCollection<TargetDrawingModel>(da.GetTargetDrawingModels());
```

or you can use foreach to add them

```
foreach (var model in da.GetTargetDrawingModels()) {
    TargetDrawings.Add(model);
}
```

You can also apply extension methods from the `System.Linq` namespace to the result like `ToList()`

```
List<TargetDrawingModel> list = da.GetTargetDrawingModels().ToList();
```

`yield return` does not terminate the method. Instead, it returns one result and pauses. When the next element is retrieved (e.g. by a foreach-loop), the method resumes. There needs not to be a `yield return` or `return` at the end. If the file-open-dialog is cancelled, then an empty enumeration is returned automatically.

---

Another option is to use a normal return-statement, but to use a [LINQ query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq) to package the result. This variant requires all paths to have a return-statement. We return an empty enumeration explicitly at the end of the method.

```
public IEnumerable<TargetDrawingModel> GetTargetDrawingModels2()
{
    using (var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() {
        Title = "Select The Target Drawings To Add To Add To The Comparison",
        Filter = "Drawing (*.dwg) | *.dwg",
        Multiselect = true
    }) {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog()) {
            return openFileDialog.FileNames
                .Select(f => new TargetDrawingModel { DrawingPath = f });
        }
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<TargetDrawingModel>();
}
```